# Missing Keyword When creating Tables and Connecting using foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this code which is oracle sql command.

I created every table alone and then linked them together using foreign key and it gives me missing keyword. As I did some search it give me that the references has something wrong

Code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Student (
    stdNo CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    lastname VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    givennames VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    dept CHAR(4)
);
CREATE TABLE Course (
  courseID CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  courseTitle VARCHAR2(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  credits INT DEFAULT 2 CHECK (credits >= 0 AND credits <= 200)
);
CREATE TABLE Semester (
  semesterID CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  semesterCode INT CHECK (semesterCode BETWEEN 1 AND 4),
  semesterYear INT CHECK (semesterYear BETWEEN 2000 AND 9999)
);
CREATE TABLE Register (
  stdNo CHAR(5),
  courseID CHAR(8),
  semesterID CHAR(5),
  grade CHAR(2),
  mark DECIMAL(4, 2),
  PRIMARY KEY (stdNo, courseID, semesterID),
  FOREIGN KEY (stdNo) REFERENCES Student(stdNo) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (courseID) REFERENCES Course(courseID),
  FOREIGN KEY (semesterID) REFERENCES Semester(semesterID),
  CHECK (mark >= 0.00 AND mark <= 100.00)
);
```

Comment: it give's me error : missing keyword

Comment: Remove `ON UPDATE CASCADE` as Oracle does not support that syntax. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/80Ft9oQF)